# Log4j2 multiple root appenders

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 in my application.

I have two rolling appenders printing same data one by one

```
<RollingFile name="service1" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/test.log" filePattern="----works-----">
            <PatternLayout pattern="----works as expected-----" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>

 <RollingFile name="service2" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/test.log" filePattern="-----works------">
            <PatternLayout pattern="----works as expected" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>

      <Root level="info"> 
            <AppenderRef ref="service1"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="service2" />
      </Root>
```

Something like this
output :-

```
Debugging data1
Debugging data1
Debugging data2
Debugging data2
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't use the same file for both `RollingFile` appenders. You are now telling Log4j to write each event twice to the same file - once through `service1` and once through `service2`.

Comment: @RobSpoor Can you please suggest any other appenders that give me same functionality as RollingFile?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `RollingFile` appender, just don't use the same file for different appenders.

Comment: Usually when you have multiple appenders they use different files for the output and they filter different data (for example one appender only for levels warning and up, the other appender for debug output)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing all logs in one file.
Change file names, for instance

```
fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/test_service1.log"
fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/test_service2.log"
```

Comment: @manu: if this answers your question (I believe it does), please mark it as accepted.